# How to get the propertygrid as big as sizer?

Tags: c++11, wxwidgets

```
wxBoxSizer* bConstantsSizer;
bConstantsSizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

m_propertyGrid1 = new wxPropertyGrid(m_scrolledWindowConstants,wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(300, 300), wxPG_DEFAULT_STYLE|wxHSCROLL|wxVSCROLL);
bConstantsSizer->Add( m_propertyGrid1, 0, wxALL, 5 );
```

I have hardcoded the size of my property grid to 300, 300, but how do it dynamically?

[image: Screenshot_20161221_015600.png]

Comment: What kind of sizer is `bConstantsSizer`? What direction do you wish to be dynamically sized?

Comment: bConstantsSizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

Comment: The sizer must be assigned to the window that contains the controls managed by the sizer. Please, read the docs and look into the samples.

Comment: @Ripi2 thanks for the answer. but I thought I am doing that in wxformbuilder.
https://s30.postimg.org/3n749n2ch/Screenshot_20161221_015600.png

Comment: @j35t3r, why do you pass a static size in the wxPropertyGrid constructor? You should use "wxDefaultSize" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `proportion` to `1` and also set `wxEXPAND` flag for it, see `sizeritem` and `sizeritembase` properties. So the result should be

```
bConstantsSizer->Add( m_propertyGrid1, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );
```

Comment: This is correct, but it's better to use `bConstantSizer->Add(m_propertyGrid1, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border())` which is much more readable.

Comment: Yup, that would be best, but in this case I don't think best practices are up to the developer. AFAICT that was generated code.